# Generating a remote firewall config with Firestarter?

Tags: iptables

Is it possible to generate iptables firewall rules using Firestarter for a system other than the one that it is running on?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do this with Firestarter, but if you are looking for this type of capability you might want to check out Firewall Builder (http://www.fwbuilder.org/).

Comment: Hmm I already at that, and it was non-free...although I saw something that appeared similar for managing an entire network called Shorewall, is that along the same lines without the GUI?

Answer (score 1):

You could generate the config you want on the local machine, run iptables-save, copy the resulting file over to the remote machine and iptables-restore (iptables-load, maybe?) the file over there. It's a few more steps than normal, but would work.